# How can I save the code of my generated HTML page?

Tags: php, html, laravel, output, laravel-9

Let me explain the problem :

I'm going to get my data from my local db and then send it as an email to my subscribers, but in an email I can't send within the HTML code, a php script, there is no server to interpret it. The only solution that I have is to do all of the work (get data and stuff) and generate the output of it as an HTML code, by doing so I wouldn't have any script php or any other type of scripts; and then I'm going to use that generated HTML code to send it via a Sendy's API. But my question is how can I save that generated HTML code ?
After some research I found that I can use the output buffering, but I don't know how to use it and where exactly I have to start/pause it.

Here is an exemple of my HTML code(it's just the strict minimal structure that's I'm going to use) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style type="text/css">* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: transparent; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-size-adjust: none;">
  <?php
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "";
    $database="";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql = "";
    $data = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="nl-container" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: transparent;" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row row-1" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

PS : I would love to do this with Laravel 9 instead of php if it's possible

Comment: Why not take advantage of [Laravel's Mail class](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#main-content)? You can generate HTML mail and use Blade templates for sending, and there appears to be a few packages to integrate Laravel with Sendy

Comment: @aynber Do you have some docs that can help me integrate Laravel with sendy?

Comment: No, sorry. I just googled `Laravel Sendy` and saw a few articles and packages. Some of them are a bit outdated with Laravel 5, but may still work.

Comment: "in an email I can't send within the HTML code" - why can't you do that? Also, how is the code you've shared related to Laravel? It does not look like it uses any Laravel features

Comment: @NicoHaase The code I shared isn't Laravel, it's just HTML5 CSS3 with a php script. I can't do it because it's generally how ‘emails’ work. No email client will execute server-side scripts.

Comment: What keeps you from rendering the code on the server then? Use a Blade template, as you do it in the rest of your application, and put the generated markup to the mail. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#configuring-the-view contains good examples for that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To achieve this, you can use output buffering in the following way:

```
<?php

function callback($buffer)
{
  // $buffer is a string containing your html output
  $response = some_email_send_function($buffer);
  return $response;
}

ob_start("callback");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style type="text/css">* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: transparent; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-size-adjust: none;">
  <?php
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "";
    $database="";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql = "";
    $data = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="nl-container" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: transparent;" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row row-1" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>

<?php

ob_end_clean();

?>
```

Comment: That does not look like the way you should go in Laravel

Comment: The question is not just fixed to laravel. "...I would love to do this with Laravel 9 instead of php if it's possible..". Plus laravel runs on php so the above can be rewritten within laravel.

Comment: I can use php instead of laravel, I just want a solution for the problem that's all

Comment: @elver can I save the $buffer as a html file? I don't know how am I going to send the email but one thing for sure I'm going to send it Through Sendy's API

Comment: @elver https://sendy.co/

Comment: @Ayoub, yes the buffer can be saved as a html file using file_put_contents('filename.htm', $buffer);

Comment: @elver I have some other questions can we discuss in private ? Thank you a lot

Comment: @Ayoub, yes sure we can discuss. How can I reach you?

Comment: @elver Do you have Discord ? if yes add me : Ayoub#8752